# Realizar random sobre un jList

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy realizando un programa que realiza un sorteo entre todos los participantes, estos pasan de un JTextArea a un JList. Cuando presiono el botón 'Confirmar' me pasa el texto del JTextArea al Jlist eliminando el texto que no sea nombres, pero cuando presiono en el botón 'Sortear' no me realiza el sorteo sobre el JList, sino sobre el textArea. Dejo el código para que quede más claro. Al momento del sorteo no puedo lograr que me lo haga con el JList de nombres.

```
    private void botonConfirmarMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                            

    // Bloquea el cuadro de texto

    jTextArea1.setEnabled(false);

    //  Crea un arreglo de String

    String[] textoConNombres = jTextArea1.getText().split("\n");


    DefaultListModel lista = new DefaultListModel();

    // Recorre el arreglo y lo llena con los nombres
    for(String nombre : textoConNombres) {
        lista.addElement(nombre);
        // Elimina el elemento si contiene alguna palabra que no sirve
        if (nombre.contains("Agregar a amigos")) {
            lista.removeElement(nombre);
        }
        if (nombre.contains("Me gusta")) {
            lista.removeElement(nombre);
        }
        if (nombre.contains(" en común")) {
            lista.removeElement(nombre);
        }
        if(nombre.contains("Amigo")){
            lista.removeElement(nombre);
        }
        if(nombre.contains("Amigos")){
            lista.removeElement(nombre);
        }
        if(nombre.contains("Seguir")){
            lista.removeElement(nombre);
        }
        if(nombre.contains("Te gusta")){
            lista.removeElement(nombre);
        }


    }


    jList1.setModel(lista);


}                                           

    private void botonSortearMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
    //  Convierte el arreglo textoConNombres a una lista listaNombres
    String[] textoConNombres = jTextArea1.getText().split("\n");
    List<String> listaNombres = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(textoConNombres));



    Random sorteo = new Random();

    //  Obtiene el valor del comboBox
    int cantTitulares = Integer.parseInt((String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem());
    ArrayList ganadorTitular = new ArrayList();

    /*  Hace el sorteo las veces que dice el comboBox
        agrega al ganador a un arrayList aparte
        lo elimina de la lista para hacer el sorteo con el resto
        de los participantes que quedan sin ganar.*/
    for (int i = 0; i < cantTitulares; i++) {

        int ganador = sorteo.nextInt(listaNombres.size());
        ganadorTitular.add(listaNombres.get(ganador));  // Obtiene el nombre de la lista según el entero elegido
        listaNombres.remove(ganador);
    }






    // Muestra el resultado en VentanaGanador
    VentanaGanador ventGanador = new VentanaGanador();
    String ganadoresStr = "<html>"; // Se crea la cadena de texto con la etiqueta inicial <html>
    for (int i = 0; i < ganadorTitular.size(); i++) {
        ganadoresStr += ganadorTitular.get(i); // agrega el primer ganador
        if (i + 1 < ganadorTitular.size()) { // verifica si existirán más ganadores
            ganadoresStr += "<br>";// si existirán más, agrega salto de línea para agregar al otro debajo de él

        }
    }
    ganadoresStr += "</html>"; // finaliza la etiqueta
    ventGanador.etiquetaGanador.setText(ganadoresStr); // ajusta el JLabel con todos los ganadores
    ventGanador.setVisible(true);






}
```

Sé que seguramente estoy haciendo mal algo en la parte del 'for' con el 'random', pero no sé qué.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saludos nuevamente, Martín.

Fíjate en esta línea dentro del método `botonSortearMouseClicked`

`String[] textoConNombres = jTextArea1.getText().split("\n");`

Ahí estás obteniendo los valores del `jTextArea1` nuevamente. Debería ser con `jList1` al cual le asignaste los valores recientemente.

EDIT:

La forma en que tendrás que obtener los valores, ya no será con `getText()`, puesto que los `JList` están conformados por `elementos` y no por cadenas de texto.

Cambia estas dos líneas:

```
String[] textoConNombres = jTextArea1.getText().split("\n");
List<String> listaNombres = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(textoConNombres));
```

por esta otra:

```
DefaultListModel listaNombres = (DefaultListModel) jList1.getModel();
```

Lo que harás será obtener el `modelo` de esa lista con los elementos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudarme siempre César. Te consulto algo, cambio de String[] textoConNombres = jTextArea1.getText().split("\n"); 
a 
String[] textoConNombres = **jList1.getText()**.split("\n"); 
pero no me lo deja usar.
¿Cuál método tendría que asignarle?

Comment: No, el `JList` no está conformado por líneas de texto en su interior como el caso del `JTextArea`,  el `JList` está conformado por `elementos`, debes obtenerlos por medio del `modelo` que asignaste, esto lo logras mediante `jList1.getModel()`. Haré unas pruebas y editaré la respuesta para darte una idea.

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias.

Comment: Revisa el `EDIT`, @Martín.

Comment: Muchas gracias, resolvió mi problema!

Comment: Con gusto, @Martín. :-). Por cierto, si por casualidad algunos nombres se muestran en líneas diferentes, se debe a que el nombre del participante es mayor al tamaño del `JLabel` y como estás utilizando `HTML` automáticamente creará un salto de línea. Lo que debes hacer es que el tamaño de ese `JLabel` sea mayor para que todo el nombre se mantenga en una misma línea.